# How to create new exceptions that extends an initial Error with TypeScript 2.9?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, error-handling, typescript-class

I wrote a small function to cascade errors in React & React Native with TypeScript:

```js
/**
 * Function that takes an error and trow an enriched error
 * @param error the original error
 * @param func the name of the function trowing the error
 * @param params the parameters passer to the function
 * @param custom a custom message to add*
 * @returns an enriched error
 */
const throwR = (error: Error, func?: string, params?: any, custom?: string) => {
  // Parse params in an human readable form
  let parsedParams: string = ''
  if (params && typeof params === 'object') {
    try {
      parsedParams = JSON.stringify(params)
    } catch (err) {
      parsedParams = `${params.toString()} (JSON.stringify returned: ${err})`
    }
  } else {
    try {
      parsedParams = params.toString()
    } catch (err) {
      parsedParams = `<params.toString(): ${err}>`
    }
  }

  // Handle the case where no error message is provided
  if (!error) {
    try {
      console.log(`on ${func}(${parsedParams})${' ' + custom}: No error message provided to throwR`)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`No error message provided to throwR and unable to build this message: ${err}`)
    }
  }

  // build the error message
  let message: string = ''
  try {
    message = `on ${func}(${parsedParams})${' ' + custom}: ${error}`
  } catch (err) {
    message = `${error} (could not build enriched message: ${err})`
  }

  // build the new error
  const newError = new Error(message)

  // add the original error name
  try {
    newError.name = error.name
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`on throwR, could not add a name to the error: ${error}`)
  }

  // by the end, throw the error
  throw newError
}

export default throwR
```

Then I use it with:

```
const myFunction(params) => {
  try {
    // potentially faulty code
  } catch (error) {
    throwR(error, 'myFunction', params, 'custom message')
  }
}
```

I went on forums and saw that most people were using a custom error class then:

```
const myFunction(params) => {
  try {
    // potentially faulty code
  } catch (error) {
    throw new CustomError(error, customParameter)
  }
}
```

I'm a begineer and don't yet understand well the implication of each method. I would like to avoid a big pitfall that would later mean that I need to refactor all my code.

Could you explain me the implications of each approach and point me to a correct method for custom errors and cascading errors?

Thanks